# How to use FirebaseUI in redirect mode without a dedicated sign-in page?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebaseui

I want to use FirebaseUI in redirect mode, as opposed to the current popup mode I'm using. But I don't want to have a separate dedicated login URL, instead I want the user to be able to log in from any URL (using a custom dialog as the UI container for FirebaseUI).

The problem I run into is that when starting the login process, I show the dialog and the user selects their auth provider, gets redirected to the auth website, but then they are redirected back to the original URL on my website.

Now the UI container dialog is not displayed and `firebaseUI.start()` doesn't get called because the webpage doesn't know that the user is in the process of logging in. The result is that nothing happens - the user is halfway through the login process.

Is there any way I can specify a URL for the first redirect? I'm not talking about the final `signInSuccessUrl` config parameter, but something similar for the first redirect back to my website?

That way I'd be able to send the original URL that started the login process along with a flag or something that tells the webpage that the user is in the middle of a login flow so that it can display the login process UI container and call `firebaseUI.start()` to perform the last redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start FirebaseUI from any URL but the underlying `signInWithRedirect` always return to the same URL. Calling `start` on redirect will complete the sign in. If you have some condition, where you don't always display the sign in UI, you can use some flag `pendingRedirect` which you save in `sessionStorage` and check before rendering the UI to complete the sign-in on return. You would clear that after rendering.

Comment: Thanks. Is this functionality missing because it could be insecure? I mean specifying a completely different URL after the first auth step? Wouldn't it be convenient to be able to at least specify additional query-string parameters to be passed to the URL after the first redirect though? Or maybe it's just me...

Comment: Actually FirebaseUI already tracks the pending status in a similar way. They just don't expose. Seems like a good feature to expose. You could also add a #hash parameter to detect that when you start the process. I don't see why it would be insecure.

Comment: @bojeil In the same vein as this question, is it possible to use the UI when the auth-container is dynamically created, and not always present on the page in the single page app? A user has to click a button for the login modal containing the auth-container to appear.